# Code is returning values like this : <function max_pt_date at 0x000002209087F040>

Tags: python, csv

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv
import random
nomfichier="grosfichier2.csv"
tableau = []

with open(nomfichier, newline='') as csvfile:
    objetcsv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for ligne in objetcsv:
            tableau.append(ligne)
            
def max_pt_date(points,date):
    points = 0
    for ligne in tableau:
        if (ligne[1] == date):
            if (int(ligne[3]) > points):
                points = int(ligne[3])
    return  points  

def listeDates():
    dates = []
    colonne = 1
    for ligne in tableau:
        if not (ligne[colonne] in dates) and ligne[colonne] != 'Date' :
            dates.append(ligne[colonne])
    return dates

def max_pt_dates_tot(date):
    tout = []
    lesDates = listeDates()
    for date in lesDates:
        tout.append([date,max_pt_date,(date)])
    return tout


def toutlesmax():
        tout = []
        for date in listeDates():
            tout.append(max_pt_dates_tot(date))
        return tout 

for ligne in toutlesmax():
    print(ligne)
```

The objective of this code is to find, in a csv file, every maximum point production per date, which is in this form : ***2022-04-20_11:58:02***.
This file includes dates from multiples months and years.

Code is returning values in a way i've never seen, can someone help me ?

Comment: it's because of this line `tout.append([date,max_pt_date,(date)])` note that you return the function `max_pt_date` without calling it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually happens when you forget to add the () at the end of a function. I think I see your problem in the max_pt_dates_tot function. There is a comma between max_pt_date and (date).

Comment: I have TypeError: max_pt_date() missing 1 required positional argument: 'date' now, what can i do ?

Comment: What line is this on?

Comment: line 32 : tout.append([date,max_pt_date(date)])

Comment: You forgot to pass the points argument to the function.

Comment: i've changed some things, i only have line 42 that causes me problems : 

for ligne in toutlesmax():
 print(ligne)

I think  toutlesmax() need to be toutlesmax(points,date) but when i change it i have :
NameError: name 'points' is not defined

Comment: Your nameerror is caused by the fact that toutlesmax does not take any parameters.